# Accidentaly ran pip with sudo

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-16.04

After that I always get permission error when trying to install anything with pip. Is there any way to safely return everything back to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have run `sudo -H pip install`; `sudo` ran `pip` as root and `pip` changed ownership of some files and directories under your home dir. Take the files back:

```
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME
```

Comment: Looks like a reasonable solution. Too bad after random googling session and playing with sudo my desktop dont have any panels or pretty much anything else

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `pip install <package name>`. Error is PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pade'. Or should I post full error?

Comment: You don't have rights for `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/`, certainly. Either use `sudo` (`sudo pip install <package name>`) or install for one user (`pip install --user <package name>`) or install in a virtual environment (`source venv/bin/activate; pip install <package name>`)

Comment: Workaround with `pip install --user <package>` helps. Thanks! But is there other solutions to return to good old `pip install <package>`?

Comment: `sudo pip install`